# Error: Access 2013 creating a table that's a linked table to Sharepoint 2007/2013

Tags: sharepoint, linked-list

I am looking at Access 2013 and when trying to create a linked table to a Sharepoint list, I keep receiving an error:

> Access Services
>   Access can't connect to the external data source because the LocalDB component or the SQL Native Client component are not installed.

That's all there is to the error.

I am an admin with "Full Control" rights to Sharepoint.  I have tried this on Sharepoint 2007 and 2013.

I'd like for it to work as it does here:
http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2012/08/30/link-to-sharepoint-lists-in-access.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To anyone with same problem above, make sure the following components are installed on the Sharepoint Server:

1. Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Local DB (SQLLocalDB.msi)
2. Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Data-Tier Application Framework (Dacframework.msi)
3. Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client (sqlncli.msi)
4. Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Transact-SQL ScriptDom (SQLDOM.MSI)
5. Microsoft System CLR Types for Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SQLSysClrTypes.msi)

Answer (score 0):

You must restart the SharePoint Server after following the install steps from the previous post.